# disable link (click) in css for parent menu not affect sub-menus?

Tags: css

I am having parent menus with list of sub-menus. I need to hide only one parent menu link without affect of that sub-menus. I used `pointer-events:none;` but it affecting the sub-menus. The sub-menus not listing when i use this. So can any one help me , i need this only in css, not in jquery or javascript. Thanks in advance.
This is my menu reference,

[image]

Comment: you want to hide the "Group Profile" but still show "SP Sports..."? can we see some HTLM...?

Comment: i need to hide link of Group Profile not a text. And show the sub menus.

Comment: Finally i did in js, with help of kup. The ans is          $('#avia-menu > li:nth-of-type(2) > a').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this,

```
HTML
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p>Group Profile</p>
            <a></a>
            <ul>
                <li>SP Sports</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    <ul>
</nav>

CSS
li {
    position: relative;
}
li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
li > a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
}
li:hover > a {
    display: none;
}
```

see if it helps...

Comment: when i over a menu it hide the menu name and showing the sub menus now. But i need to show the parent menu text also. Any other possible ways there

Comment: so you want the text to appear but not be a link?

Comment: I've edited the answer, basically you need to put the text on another element, and then position the link above it

Comment: don't forget to give the "a" the same size as the "p" ;)

Comment: so i need to change the content "a" to "p" tag? But i cant change html values. The menus are generating dynamically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84579/discussion-between-jagan-akash-and-kup).

Comment: Finally i have did in js, The answer is $('#avia-menu > li:nth-of-type(2) > a').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });   Thanks kup....